# I want to search for some information about “subsectionstyle=show/show/hide”, because I dont understand it？

Tags: beamer

I've read several books. But I can not find some material that can explain the meaning of `subsectionstyle=show/show/hide` and `\tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection,subsectionstyle=show/show/hide]`，
what the meaning of them， the red arrow points to the sentence？

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `frame` environment indicates that the code is for a `beamer` presentation, and in the [`beamer` manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) you will find those things described. See in section 10.5 **Adding a table of contents**.

I quote some relevant passages:

> `\tableofcontents[⟨comma-separated option list⟩]`
>
> The following options can be given:
>
> - `currentsection` causes all sections but the current to be shown in a semi-transparent way. Also, all subsections but those in the current section are shown in the semi-transparent way. This command is
>     a shorthand for specifying the following options:
>
>   ```
>   sectionstyle=show/shaded,subsectionstyle=show/show/shaded
>   ```
> - `currentsubsection` causes all subsections but the current subsection in the current section to be shown in a semi-transparent way. This command is a shorthand for specifying the option
>     `subsectionstyle=show/shaded`.
>
> [...]
>
> - `subsectionstyle=⟨style for current subsection⟩/⟨style for other subsections in current section⟩/⟨style for subsections in other sections⟩` specifies how subsections should be displayed. The same styles
>     as for the `sectionstyle` option may be given. You can omit the last style, in which case the second
>     also applies to the last, and you can omit the last two, in which case the first applies to all.
>
>   [...]
>
>   Example: `subsectionstyle=show/show/hide` causes all subsections outside the current section to be suppressed.
>
>   Example: `subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide` causes all subsections outside the current section to be suppressed and only the current subsection in the current section to be highlighted.